# SQL DateTime field displays as DateTime? in C# classes created by Entity Framework

Tags: c#, sql-server, entity-framework, datetime

Through Visual Studio I have used Entity Framework to create classes corresponding to SQL Server Tables.
In the SQL Server table some fields are defined as "datetime" with a default value of (getutcdate()).
The Datetime fields in the C# classes that map to the database table datetime fields have an appended "?"

[Click to see C# class](https://i.stack.imgur.com/nvY8O.jpg)

Can anyone tell me what this "?" means and if I need to do anything to prevent some looming disaster?
Grateful for any advice.

Comment: `?` mean this field can be `null`.

Comment: Thanks Triv .  Do you know if that's documented anywhere so I can read up on it?

Comment: Here it is https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/2cf62fcy.aspx

Comment: Thanks TriV - a helpful reference.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

DateTime? is syntactical sugar for `Nullable<DateTime>`, which means that the value can store either a datetime, or null. A regular `DateTime` cannot store null, so developers may uses something like `DateTime.Min` to represent "no value set" (bad practice though).

The reason your generated classes have a `DateTime?` is likely because your column does not have `NOT NULL` constraint (different from a default value). I.e. since the server CAN store a NULL in the `EntityDoB` field, the generated class has to be able to handle a NULL date time in code.

The code won't fall over, and (assuming you can have a non-specified date) is correct. You just need to consider how Nullable's will impact your code, and be aware that Entity-Framework does not respect default database columns - if C# knows about the column, EF will specify a value.